# Uncaught Type Error: val.split is not a function react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I have use skills select but the skills is not set and show uncaught error in react-redux

Here's the code:

```
skillChange(val,i,e) {
var skills = val.split(',')
if (val === '') {
  this.setState({skills:val, selectedSkills:[], skillsErrMessage: ''})
} else {
   const state = this.state.portfolio[i]
   state.skills = e.target.value
   state.skillsErrMessage = ''
   this.setState(state)
  }
}
```

In render:

```
<Select multi simpleValue disabled={this.state.disabled}
  placeholder="Select skills"
  value={item.skills}
  options={this.state.skillsArr}
  onChange={this.skillChange.bind(this, index)}
  errorText={item.skillsErrMessage}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index` variable that is being passed to the `onChange` function is most likely an `Number`. `Number` in JavaScript has no method called `split`.

You want to pass a comma separated string for it to work.

Comment: It's not working I have use comma seperated string but same error

Comment: That can't be - if you `console.log(val);` what does that give you? Simple example here http://jsbin.com/muxomojido/edit?html,js,output